# Program keeps spamming numbers?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int a;
  int b;
  int dif;
  cout<<"insert a: "<<endl;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"insert b: "<<endl;
  cin>>b;
  if(a>b){
    while(dif>=3){
      dif=a-b;
      cout<<dif;
    }
  }else{
    while(dif>=3){
      dif=b-a;
      cout<<dif;
    }
  }  
}
```

This is supposed to be a program that reads two numbers and keeps subtracting the smaller one from the bigger one until the difference is < 3 units. While it does this it should also output the difference at every iteration and for some reason it spams the difference or doesnt output anything. Help?

Comment: **A)** `while(dif>=3)` at first pass is UB: you are reading a non-initialized variable. **B)** Let's assume that `a` is `10` and `b` is `5` and you actually initialize `dif` to `a - b = 10 - 5 = 5` _before_ reading `dif` (i.e., removing the UB), then you will enter an never terminating `while` loop at `while(dif>=3)`, as the `dif` is just re-calculated over and over again to the same value (namely `a-b = 10 = 5 = 5`).

Comment: Take a look at [do-while-loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do). You are currently checking the value of `dif` before it is set.

Comment: If you fortunately or unfortunately came into the loops, the loops may run infinitely because `a` and `b` don't seem to be updated and `dif` won't change.

Comment: OK, you want "keeps subtracting the smaller one from the bigger one" and discard the results of the subtraction?

Comment: Well what did you expect it to do? You have: `while(dif >= 3) {dif = a-b; cout << dif;}`. So it'll set dif to a-b, and it'll print dif, and it'll keep doing that forever because dif is always the same number

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in your while loops:

```
while(dif>=3){
  dif=a-b;
  cout<<dif;
}
```

First, `dif` is used uninitialized and using it will cause undefined behavior. After you fix that the loop will still not do what you want.

`dif=a-b;` will assign to `dif` the same value in every iteration, hence the loop will run either never (condition is `false` before the loop), once (condition is `false` after the assignment), or forever (condition is still `true` after the assignment). I suppose this isn't the intended behavior.

> ...and keeps subtracting the smaller one from the bigger one until the difference is < 3 units.

You forgot to actually subtract one number from the other. That would be (in case `a` is the bigger):

```
while ( a-b >= 3) a -= b;
```

or with an additional variable (I don't think it helps, but rather adds complexity):

```
int diff = a-b;
while (diff >= 3) {
    a -= b;
    diff = a-b;
}
```

Comment: If a-b is negative then it will never enter the loop even it is difference is bigger than 3 so absolute is required.

Comment: @imran  OPs code can be refactored to reduce code duplication but I dont see how `abs` would fit in here, because they always want to substract the smaller from the bigger

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue here ..

1. diff is not assigned any default value so it gets random value, if it will be greater or equal than 3 it will print infinity and if it is less than it will do nothing.
   initiaalize the diff with `diff=abs(b-a)`
2. if by chance diff enter the loop then on every iteration diff is not changing as a and b remain same. So change the logic.
3. Instead of if else and two while loops just use `diff=abs(b-a)`

Good Luck

Comment: it doesnt get a random value. Thats a misleading myth

Comment: `abs` is from `stdlib.h`, not `math.h`.

Comment: Mike thanks for correcting. You r right. I am correcting it with edit

Comment: how do you know which number to substract from which, when you only consider `abs(a-b)` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 He says that we have to find the difference of two numbers, until the difference is less than three ... So it is difference .... subtracting smaller from bigger is because not to get negative value ... So absolute does the same

Comment: OP wants to substract the smaller from the bigger until the difference is less than 3. Once you know which one is bigger and which one is smaller you dont need `abs`

Comment: Why to add extra logic if it can be solved by simple

Comment: we are talking past each other. My point is: I dont understand how you want to solve it. As I see it using `abs` is extra logic.

Comment: The fact that OP reads `dif` when its uninitialized doesn't guarantee that it gets a random value. It may get [nasal daemons](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/nasal_demons) instead.

Comment: suppose you get two numbers, then you calculate `abs(a-b)`, what would be the next step? what number do you subtract from which?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize dif to be a number, e.g. `int dif = 0;`. C++ doesn't say what happens when you manipulate or use an uninitialized variable, so anything can happen and your program won't work consistently- this is probably why you've had it produce no output. This phenomenon is known as undefined behavior- see [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/#:%7E:text=An%20uninitialized%20variable%20is%20a,will%20result%20in%20undefined%20behavior.) for a full explanation.

Additionally, your loops also go infinite- if `a` is greater than `b`, `dif >=3`, and you set `dif = a - b`, `dif` is always the same, so the condition will always be true, and thus your code never stops running. You need to subtract and reassign the variable first so the values change, and then update `dif`:

```
a = a - b
dif = a - b
```

The second loop has the same problem.